# AWS Amplify TypeError: S3 is not a constructor when bundling with Parcel

Tags: aws-amplify, parceljs

I am using the [AWS Amplify Storage module](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/storage) to store and retrieve user files using the JavaScript API. When I serve or build with [Parcel](https://parceljs.org/), the following error message is printed to the console:

```
TypeError: S3 is not a constructor
    at AWSS3Provider._createS3 (AWSS3Provider.ts:501)
    at AWSS3Provider.<anonymous> (AWSS3Provider.ts:130)
    at step (AWSS3Provider.ts:19)
    at Object.next (AWSS3Provider.ts:19)
    at fulfilled (AWSS3Provider.ts:19)
```

The error occurs with Parcel `v1.12.4` and AWS Amplify `v2.2.4`.

### Minimal steps to reproduce

An appropriately configured Cognito identity pool and S3 bucket per the [AWS Amplify Storage documentation](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/storage#manual-setup) are needed.

The following files should all be in the same directory.

A `package.json` with dependencies.

```
{
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "aws-amplify": "^2.2.4",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15"
  }
}
```

An `aws-exports.js` that specifies the identity pool and S3 bucket:

```
export const awsconfig = {
  Auth: {
    identityPoolId: "xx-xxxx-x:xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
    region: "xx-xxxx-x"
  },
  Storage: {
    AWSS3: {
      bucket: "a-bucket-name",
      region: "xx-xxxx-x"
    }
  }
};
```

An `index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <body>
    <main></main>
    <script src="./index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

An `index.js`:

```
import Amplify, { Storage } from "aws-amplify";
import { awsconfig } from "./aws-exports";
Amplify.configure(awsconfig);

// not required, but helps to confirm everything else worked
window.LOG_LEVEL = "DEBUG";

Storage.get("test.txt")
  .then(result => console.log(result))
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Run the following

```
npm install
parcel index.html
```

then view the page and error message in the console.

Note that replacing the call to `Storage.get()` with `Storage.configure()` does not produce an error.

I have tried bundling the same with a default `webpack` configuration, and I do not observe the error. This makes me suspect that I may need to override some `parcel` configuration.

Answer (score 4):

I encountered this when deploying Lambdas using `@aws-cdk/aws-lambda-nodejs`.

I worked around this by using the `aws-sdk` available in the Lambda runtime environment instead of bundling my own copy in each Lambda's assets. It should equally apply to other assets that end up running in Lambda.

```sh
npm install --save-dev parcel-plugin-externals
```

Add to `package.json`:

```
"externals": [
    "aws-sdk"
]
```

Instantiate S3 client using

```js
import * as AWS from 'aws-sdk';
const s3 = new AWS.S3();
```

instead of

```js
import * as S3 from 'aws-sdk/clients/s3';
const s3 = new S3();
```

References:

- https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/7685